# Android saving large bitmaps

Tags: android, bitmap

I'm new to `android` and I'm confused about how to deal with `Bitmaps`.

I want to download a `Bitmap`, it could be quite large, and save it to a temporary internal file.  I'm then going to draw this `Bitmap` to a `Canvas` later.

My current method is to 
 1. Download the input stream
 2. copy the stream
 3. use one stream to work out bounds using `bitmapFactory.options`
 4. use the other stream to decode the full bitmap with the sample size

However, I need `landscape` and `portrait` versions, so now I will have to do this twice and save two images.

Or - I have seen people use `bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, bos);` to save a file instead.  This by-passes the decoding with sample size as its saved direct from a stream.  I guess then I would use a matrix to scale when I draw to my `Canvas`.

Basically, I am confused as the best approach for this task , which method is less likely to run into out of memory and is the more commonly used approach?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
  byte[] imagesByte = getLogoImage(Your url);
```

**set to imageview...**

```
 imgView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray( imagesByte,  0, imagesByte.length));
```

**Method for Download**

```
 public static byte[] getLogoImage(String url){
            try {
                URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
                URLConnection ucon = imageUrl.openConnection();

                InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);

                ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(500);
                int current = 0;
                while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
                    baf.append((byte) current);
                }

                return baf.toByteArray();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("ImageManager", "Error: " + e.toString());
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: I can't use this method as I want to save to internal storage, I'm also drawing to canvas later - I don't have an image view.

Answer (score 0):

In Android you have to e aware of limited memory, so large images would't fit in memory and you will have OutOfMemory exceptions.

The key is, after saving te image in internal storage, load it at the display resolution:

First download te image, this should be done outside the UI thread, let `_url` an `URL` intance with the image addres and `_file` the String containing destination file :

```
URLConnection conn = _url.openConnection();
        conn.connect();
        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
        boolean success = false; //track succesful operation

        if( _file != null)
        {
            try
            {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(_file);
                byte data[] = new byte[4086]; //use 4086 bytes buffer

                int count = 0;
                while ((count = is.read(data)) != -1)
                {
                    fos.write(data, 0, count);//write de data
                }

                is.close();
                fos.flush();
                fos.close();

                int len =  conn.getContentLength();
                File f = new File( _file);//check fie length is correct
                if( len== f.length())
                {
                    success = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    //error downloading, delete de file
                    File tmp = new File( _file);
                    if( tmp.exists())
                    {
                        tmp.delete();
                    }
                }
            }catch (Exception e )
            {
                try
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    //delete file with errors
                    File tmp = new File( _file);
                    if( tmp.exists())
                    {
                        tmp.delete();
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                is.close();//cleanup

            }
```

Then when you have to load the image at the desired resolution, here the key is use BitmapFactory to read bitmap info and get scaled bitmap:

```
public static Bitmap bitmapFromFile(int width, int height, String file)
{

    Bitmap bitmap = null;

    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

    if( height >0 && width > 0 ) {
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;//only read bitmap metadata
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file,options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, width, height);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

    }
    try
    {
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file, options);//decode scaled bitmap
    }catch (Throwable t)
    {
        if( bitmap != null)
        {
            bitmap.recycle();//cleanup memory, very important!
        }
        return null;

    }
    return bitmap
}
```

The final step is to calculate the scale factor:

```
public static int calculateInSampleSize(
        BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {


    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height;
        final int halfWidth = width;

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while ((couldShrink(halfWidth, reqWidth, inSampleSize)&&
                couldShrink(halfHeight,reqHeight, inSampleSize))
                //&&(halfHeight*halfWidth)/inSampleSize > maxsize)
                )
        {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }

    }

    return inSampleSize;
}
private static  boolean couldShrink ( int dimension, int req_dimension, int divider)
{
    int actual = dimension / divider;
    int next = dimension / (divider*2);

    int next_error = Math.abs(next - req_dimension);
    int actual_error = Math.abs(actual-req_dimension);

    return next > req_dimension ||
            (actual > req_dimension && (next_error < actual_error) )
            ;
}
```

That is if you want to do it by hand, I recommend you to use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) that will handle donwloading, disk caching and memory caching of your image:

To load into a ImageView called `image` showing a backgroud (`R.drawable.img_bg`) while downloading :

```
Picasso.with(image.getContext())
            .load(url).placeholder(R.drawable.img_bg).fit()
                    .into(image, new Callback.EmptyCallback()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess()
                        {
                            holder.progress.setVisibility(View.GONE); //hide progress bar
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError()
                        {
                            holder.progress.setVisibility(View.GONE); //hide progress bar
                            //do whatever you design to show error
                        }
                    });
```

to handle yourself a bitmap:

```
//first declare a target
_target = new Target()
    {
        @Override
        public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from)
        {
            //handle your bitmap (store it and use it on you canvas
        }

        @Override
        public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable)
        {
            //handle your fail state

        }

        @Override
        public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable)
        {//for example for drawing a placeholder while downloading
        }
    };
```

Now you just have to load and resize your image:

```
Picasso.with(context).load(url).resize(192, 192).centerCrop().into(_target);
```

Hope that helps.